# swift programming language tuple

Tags: swift

I'm relatively new to the programming scene (my only experience was C++ in first year engineering) and I'm trying to teach myself Swift language. I have the Swift Programming Language e-book from the App Store and came across the Function and Closure section regarding Tuples and am currently confused. The code they provide as an example is:

```
func calculateStatistics(scores:[Int]) -> (min:Int, max:Int, sum:Int) {
    var min = scores[0]
    var max = scores[0]
    var sum = 0
    for score in scores {
        if score > max {
            max = score
        } else if score < min {
            min = score
        }
        sum += score
    }
    return (min, max, sum)
}
let calculateStatistics([5, 3, 100, 3, 9])
```

and it'll output (3, 100, 120).

I'm just not sure about the process of how they get those values via the For-Loop and if-statement.

If any one of you can kindly walk me through whats exactly is happening in this if-statement that would be greatly appreciated!! My thinking is obviously wrong but the way I viewed it was that the min and max value is "5" by the initial variable declaration. But what is the initial value of "score" and how do you determine if score is > or < the max and min?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are just a group of values. The function is declared to return a tuple of three ints. At the end of the function there's a return statements where the resulting tuple is created from existing variables.

As for the loops and ifs, they just go through the list given as the parameter to the function, and find the highest and lowest values in the list, like this:

1. `max` is initialized to be the first value in the list. (It has to have an initial values so that it can be compared against other values with `<` and `>`.)
2. Go through every int in the list with `for score in scores` (`score` is initialized to be the next value in the list with each iteration: first it's `5`, then `3`, then `100`, etc.).
3. If an int is found to be greater than `max`, `max` is updated to that value.
4. After going through every int in the list, `max` will have the value of the greatest int in that list.

And same for `min`.

**Edit:** In the *Swift Programming Language* e-book, a few pages before *Functions and Closures*, there's an explanation on the `for-in` loop structure. Check it out.